# how to make length of items of list same as longest one in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

for instance:
`makeSame ["ab", "bad", "mammy"]` then the output is `["ab***","bad**", "mammy"]`
for each missed char get a `'*'`

```
makeSame:: [String] -> [String]
makeSame m = let f = length  (last (sort m))
  in 
    (\x ->replicate length x x ++'*') m
```

but is even not compiling.

Comment: What compilation error it gives?

Comment: What do you think `replicate length x x` do? And why you think so?

Comment: Your calculation of max length is wrong (try `["aa", "b"]` it give `1` instead of `2`).

Comment: i am try now again, will be touch as soon as i did @talex

Comment: @talex thanks for your contribution!, i shared my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get max length you can:

```
maxLength list = maximum $ map length list
```

to duplicate character use `replicate` (example `replicate 3 '*'` gives `"***"`).

All you need to do is combine this two methods.

To determine number of missing characters you need to subtract length of string (`length "somestring"` give it to you) from max length.

Comment: to getting max items of list is clear, i did as well but the problem is how to determine the number of missed char then add it

Comment: @mWelt I extended my ansver.

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution with helper function by @talex

```
longest :: [String] -> Int
longest m = maximum $ map length m

makeSame :: [String] -> [String]
makeSame m = map (\ x -> x ++ replicate (longest m- length x) '*') m
```